# Elixir Phoenix error in generated query

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm an elixir/phoenix newbie trying to figure out the basics so I can get up to speed. I'm having a hard time understanding what is wrong with the following schema definition that is making the generated query incorrect.

Side note: I am using the Tds.Ecto adapter to access a read only MS SQL Server 2005 database.

```
defmodule Rodes.Sigcdpro do
    use Ecto.Schema
    import Ecto.Changeset
    alias Rodes.Sigcdpro

    @primary_key {:cpros, :string, []}
    @derive {Phoenix.Param, key: :cpros}

    schema "sigcdpro" do
        # field :cpros, :string
        field :dpros, :string
    end

    @doc """
    Tabela de produtos
    """

    def changeset( %Sigcdpro{} = sigcdpro, attrs ) do
        sigcdpro
        |> cast( attrs, [:cpros, :dpros] )
    end
end
```

Then, when I run the following command on the interactive shell, I get an error.

```
iex(8)> Rodes.Repo.all(from p in Rodes.Sigcdpro, where: p.cpros == 'R1156CRY.R1')
[debug] QUERY ERROR source="sigcdpro" db=227.0ms
SELECT s0.[cpros], s0.[dpros] FROM [sigcdpro] AS s0 WHERE (s0.[cpros] = 82, 49, 49, 53, 54, 67, 82, 89, 46, 82, 49) []
** (Tds.Error) Line 1 (Error 102): Incorrect syntax near ','.
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:431: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute_and_cache/7
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:133: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:37: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
iex(8)>
```

Comment: Try double quotes: `p.cpros == "R1156CRY.R1"`.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the schema postoed has it’s `cpros` field commented out. Also, @Dogbert’s suggestion should work: single quotes are _absolutely_ different from double quotes in Elixir. There is many written about it in all the tutorials, basically `'R11'` is _a list_, not _a string_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing single quotes to double should work:

```
Rodes.Repo.all(from p in Rodes.Sigcdpro, where: p.cpros == "R1156CRY.R1")
```

Single quoted strings are charlists which are lists of integers (`'foo' == [102, 111, 111]`). I think the behavior of `Tds.Ecto` is not good here -- it should handle charlists in a better way, either throwing a proper error when the types don't match or somehow passing the array in such a way that it doesn't cause a syntax error (I have no idea about what queries MSSQL supports). You might want to report this in their repo if it hasn't already been reported.